# Incompatibility of output size of pooling layer in CNN model described in Caffe vs Matlab

Tags: matlab, caffe, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I have a Caffe CNN model, and I am trying to import it to MATLAB using `importCaffeNetwork` command, which gets prototxt and caffemodel files as input arguments.
However, I get this error:

> ```
> The pooling layer 'pool1' is not compatible with MATLAB. 
> Caffe computes the output size as [16 16 32] but MATLAB computes it as [15 15 32]
> ```

It seems that the error is related to the difference in output size calculation of pooling layer in MATLAB and CAFFE, where the former uses `ceil` and the latter uses `floor` function.

Is it the real source of problem?
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is because in caffe, the output size calculation for convolution layers and pooling layers are slightly different. Suppose input dim is `h`, padding is `p`, kernel size is `k` and stride is `s`, for convolutional layers, the output size is
`floor((h+2*p-k)/s)+1`,
but for pooling layers, the output size is `ceil((h+2*p-k)/s)+1`.

So the output size is different even if the parameters and input size are the same.

#### How to solve this problem?

Adjust the parameter such as padding and stride and kernel size to ensure that the output is the same.

#### References

1. Pooling layer output size calculation source code, https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp#L90
2. Conv layers output size calculation source code, https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp#L18

Comment: Thanks for the information about the source of problem. However, adjusting the variables in this way is limiting. Is there any way to change some sort of settings? Or is it possible to simply modify the mentioned codes such that this problem does not arise at all?

Comment: Maybe you can paste the part of code that is relevant to this problem so that I can know what the problem is.

Comment: I mean that, is it possible that I change just this part of code in CAFFE and "make" it again to become compatible with MATLAB?